# Delete/remove dynamically loaded javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to delete or remove a javascript file after it has served its purpose?

This is the function I use to bring in the js.

```
function start() {   
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'application/javascript';
    script.src= 'somefile.js';
    script.async = true;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Could I do something similar with a `stop()` function to remove the js file?

EDIT: bit of a workaround but I've used

```
function reload(){
location.reload();
}
```

to reload the page, thus deleteing the JS.

Comment: what's the intent behind this?

Comment: You could remove the <script> tag from DOM, but the scripts were already executed; it won't make a difference.

Comment: the loaded js is a recording function, so after the user has done recording I would like it to be removed so additional input won't be saved

Comment: sounds like that's something that should be built into your recording code then.  you should allow it to start / stop programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to remove the Javascript file, the stop() function could just set a flag that causes the script to do nothing.

Comment: is there a simple way to disable an entire script?

Comment: Not that I know of. What I meant was that every function in the script that can be called externally should test the flag. And any functions that are registered to be called back asynchronously should be unregistered, if possible.